# How to build accordion from an array by mapping its elements in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For building this accordion I used [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example)

**Accordion:**

```
                        <div className="accordion" id="typesAcc">
                            {types.map((type, id) => (
                                <div className="card">
                                    <div className="card-header mx-auto" id={`heading${id}`}>
                                        <h5>
                                            <button className="btn collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target={`#collapse${id}`} aria-expanded="false" aria-controls={`collapse${id}`}>
                                                {type.title}
                                            </button>
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id={`collapse${id}`} className="collapse" aria-labelledby={`heading${id}`} data-parent="#typesAcc">
                                        <div class=" card card-body lead">
                                            {type.article}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
```

**Types Array:**

```
        const types = [
            {
                title: 'Title 1',
                article: 'Article 1'
            },
            {
                title: 'Title 2',
                article: 'Article 2'
            }
        ]
```

But when I am clicking on the button containing the title of current `type`, then the `article` won't show up. It remains collapsed. How to solve this?

Comment: Change the attribute class to className in ` <div class=" card card-body lead">`.

Comment: Yeah it throws a warning, but I don't know why the article remains collapsed.

Comment: i don't see any onClick handlers on your button . How are you toggling the state of the collapsed? Also are you using any other libraries to render your accordion ?

Comment: @Shyam I didn't use onClick handlers but referring to [Bootstrap's Accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example) I did use other's. I guess now I will try this using css and onClick handlers. I still can't find the problem here in using Bootstrap tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button doesn't have any click handler assigned to it, that would set some state and cause re-render of the component. If you are using bootstrap library I recommend check-out this documentation: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

Please add event handlers to the buttons.

See more on event handling here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: I did use the attributes which handle this accordion such as data-toggle, etc. as shown here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example